# How to get html content of custom element on button click in angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am loading the html template using directive as stated in this post [Is it possible to allow user to edit and save html template in angularjs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278726/is-it-possible-to-allow-user-to-edit-and-save-html-template-in-angularjs-applica)

I am allowing user to change text in the loaded content and want to save updated html back to the database. Can someone please help me how can read the updated html on button click in angularjs controller?

Comment: no answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using TinyMCE editor control in my application. Just sharing it in case anyone is looking for such behavior. Details about this control can be found on their website https://www.tinymce.com/